# Calculate Value DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView With id, Depense, Recette and Balance:

Balance is calculated by add previous Balance + Depence + Recette.

I have 3 button, AddProduct,UpdateProduct and DeleteProduct.

- AddProduct : it will add a line into the DataGridView, but if the DataGridView is empty, (1st line) Balance = 0+10+10, and if isn't, (3rd line) Balance = 60+30+30=120.
- UpdateProduct: I f I update a line, it will affect the other data, example, if I update the last line with Depense and Recette = 50, so the Balance in last will be 220 and.
- DeleteProduct : also the same idea with UpdateProduct's button but just remove the Balance from affected lines. I delete the 2nd line, o the 3rd and 4th line was affected.

[image]

My problem how to do this?

**Update :
Code for Showing the Data in DataGridView**

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataGridViewTresorerie.DataSource = null;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select IdTre,Depense,Recette,Balance from Tresorerie", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        DataGridViewTresorerie.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 2 : I add a method that calculate the balance from 2nd row in DataGridView then I call the method in add, update, and delete, but nothing happen.**

```
 Decimal BalanceInput;
    int IdTreInput;
    private void UpdateBalance()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            BalanceInput = Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i - 1].Cells[12].Value);
            IdTreInput = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Tresorerie set Balance= @Balance  WHERE IdTre = @IdTre", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", BalanceInput);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTre", IdTreInput);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            //I call the new DataGridView to recalculate again after modify or add or delete the new data
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
```

**Update 3 : I modify the code and I call it when I click o button for test, the 1st click works perfect, but when I click again it add again sum, so I add another 'for' to calculate the balance for every row alone, but nothing happen, it stays the same problem**

```
Decimal BalanceInput=0;
    int IdTreInput;
    private void UpdateBalance()
    {
        // calculate again somme of balance
        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            BalanceInput = Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value);
            IdTreInput = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Tresorerie set Balance= @Balance  WHERE IdTre = @IdTre", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", BalanceInput);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTre", IdTreInput);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        // update balance
        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)

                BalanceInput = Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);
            else
            {
                BalanceInput += Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);
                IdTreInput = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewTresorerie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Tresorerie set Balance= @Balance  WHERE IdTre = @IdTre", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", BalanceInput);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTre", IdTreInput);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                //I call the new DataGridView to recalculate again after modify or add or delete the new data
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We see you have a DataGrid**View**, but what **data** do you have? In other words, are you using bound or unbound mode? If bound, what is the type of the data source?

Comment: I get the date from sql server, and show it in the datagridview, after calculated the new balance for every line, I update the table.

Comment: What I'm asking is do you use something like this `gridView.DataSource = something;`. And if yes, show that `something`.

Comment: Ok, so it's a `DataTable` and has `Balance` column. All you need is after every `Add`, `Update` or `Delete` **DataRow** in the **table**, update accordingly the related **DataRows** in the **table**. The grid will show that automatically.

Comment: ok I do that, but nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant in the comments was to update the underlying data source - in your case it's the `DataTable` that is assigned to the `DataGridView.DataSource`. Something like this

```
static void UpdateBalance(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    var dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource;
    var recetteColumn = dataTable.Columns["Recette"];
    var depenseColumn = dataTable.Columns["Depense"];
    var balanceColumn = dataTable.Columns["Balance"];
    decimal balance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var dataRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
        balance += (decimal)dataRow[recetteColumn] + (decimal)dataRow[depenseColumn];
        dataRow[balanceColumn] = balance;
    }
}
```

Call this anytime you want to update the balance. The data grid view will automatically update.